# Constructible n-gons

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

A [constructible \$n\$-gon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon) is a regular polygon with n sides that you can construct with only a compass and an unmarked ruler.

As stated by Gauss, the only \$n\$ for which a \$n\$-gon is constructible is a product of any number of distinct Fermat primes and a power of \$2\$ (ie. \$n = 2^k \times p_1 \times p_2 \times ...\$ with \$k\$ being an integer and every \$p_i\$ some distinct Fermat prime).

A Fermat prime is a prime which can be expressed as \$2^{2^n}+1\$ with \$n\$ a positive integer. The only known Fermat primes are for \$n = 0, 1, 2, 3 \text{ and } 4\$

## The challenge

Given an integer \$n>2\$, say if the \$n\$-gon is constructible or not.

## Specification

Your program or function should take an integer or a string representing said integer (either in unary, binary, decimal or any other base) and return or print a truthy or falsy value.

This is code-golf, so shortest answer wins, [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

[Relevant OEIS](https://oeis.org/A003401)

## Examples

```
3 -> True
9 -> False
17 -> True
1024 -> True
65537 -> True
67109888 -> True
67109889 -> False
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

*Thanks to Sp3000 for saving 2 bytes.*

```
ÆṪBSỊ
```

Uses the following classification:

> These are also the numbers for which phi(n) is a power of 2.

Where *phi* is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function).

```
ÆṪ        # Compute φ(n).
  B       # Convert to binary.
   S      # Sum bits.
    Ị     # Check whether it's less than or equal to 1. This can only be the
          # case if the binary representation was of the form [1 0 0 ... 0], i.e. 
          e# a power of 2.
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4bhuapCU-G7ig&input=&args=NjcxMDk4ODg)

Alternatively (credits to xnor):

```
ÆṪ’BP
ÆṪ        # Compute φ(n).
  ’       # Decrement.
   B      # Convert to binary.
    P     # Product. This is 1 iff all bits in the binary representation are
          # 1, which means that φ(n) is a power of 2.
```

A direct port of [my Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92273/8478) is two bytes longer:

```
ÆṪ        # Compute φ(n).
  µ       # Start a new monadic chain, to apply to φ(n).
   ÆṪ     # Compute φ(φ(n)).
      H   # Compute φ(n)/2.
     =    # Check for equality.
```

Comment: I don't know Jelly, but could you perhaps check power of 2 by factoring and checking if the maximum is 2? You can also check if the bitwise AND of it and its predecessor is 0.

Comment: @xnor Hm, good idea but my attempts at that are the same length. If there's a way to check if a list is of length 1 in less than 3 bytes, it would be shorter though (by using the factorisation function that just gives a list of exponents). I can't find a way to do that though.

Comment: I see there's E to check if all element of a list are equal. What if you double the number, factor it, and check if all factors are equal?

Comment: @xnor That's also a nice idea. :) That would probably be 6 bytes then, but Sp3000 pointed out that there's `B` and `Ị` which let me test it in 5.

Comment: Ah, nice. Any chance that decrement, then binary, then product is shorter?

Comment: @xnor That would also be 5: `ÆṪ’BP`

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
e=EulerPhi
e@e@#==e@#/2&
```

Uses the following classification from OEIS:

> Computable as numbers such that cototient-of-totient equals the totient-of-totient.

The [totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) `φ(x)` of an integer `x` is the number of positive integers below `x` that are coprime to `x`. The cototient is the number of positive integers that aren't, i.e. `x-φ(x)`. If the totient is equal to the cototient, that means that the totient of `φ(x) == x/2`.

The more straightforward classification

> These are also the numbers for which phi(n) is a power of 2.

ends up being a byte longer:

```
IntegerQ@Log2@EulerPhi@#&
```

Comment: What are cototients and totients? And are cototient-of-totients and totient-of-totients ratios?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp The totient of `n` is the number of integers below `n` that are coprime to `n`, and the cototient is the number of integers below `n` that aren't. I'll edit in a link.

Comment: Mathematica's built-in will never stop to amaze me

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp As for your second question it just means that you compute the (co)totient of the totient of `n`.

Answer (score 3):

### Retina, <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```
0+$

+`^(.*)(?=(.{16}|.{8}|....|..?)$)0*\1$
$1
^1$
```

Input is in binary. The first two lines divide by a power of two, the next two divide by all known Fermat primes (if in fact the number is a product of Fermat primes). Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @Martin Ender♦.

Comment: binary input is fine, as well as the assumption about Fermat primes

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES7), 61 bytes

```
n=>[...Array(5)].map((_,i)=>n%(i=2**2**i+1)?0:n/=i)&&!(n&n-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Actually, 6 bytes

This answer is based on [xnor's algorithm in Martin Ender's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92275/47581). Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4paSROKUnOKZguKJiM-A&input=MTc)

```
▒D├♂≈π
```

**How it works**

```
         Implicit input n.
▒        totient(n)
 D       Decrement.
  ├      Convert to binary (as string).
   ♂≈    Convert each char into an int.
     π   Take the product of those binary digits.
         If the result is 1,
           then bin(totient(n) - 1) is a string of 1s, and totient(n) is power of two.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 97 bytes

```
@set/pn=
@for /l %%a in (4,-1,0)do @set/a"p=1<<(1<<%%a),n/=p*!(n%%-~p)+1"
@cmd/cset/a"!(n-1&n)"
```

Input is on stdin in decimal. This is actually 1 byte shorter than calculating the powers of powers of 2 iteratively. I saved 1 byte by using @xnor's power of 2 check.