# Generating Fermat primes

Tags: code-golf, primes

Given a number n, print the nth **prime** Fermat number, where the Fermat numbers are of the form 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>+1. This code should theoretically work for any n (i.e. don't hardcode it), although it is not expected to terminate for n > 4. (It should **not** return 4294967297 for n=5, as 4294967297 is not a prime number.)

Do note that while all Fermat primes are of the form 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>+1, not all numbers of the form 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>+1 are prime. The goal of this challenge is to return the n-th **prime.**

## Test cases

```
0 -> 3
1 -> 5
2 -> 17
3 -> 257
4 -> 65537
```

## Rules

- Standard loopholes are disallowed.
- 0-indexing and 1-indexing are both acceptable.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count wins.

Related: [Constructible n-gons](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92272/constructible-n-gons)

Comment: Am I or are some of the answers misinterpreting the challenge? Aren't we simply writing a program that outputs `2^(2^n) + 1`, where `n` is the input? This lines up with your test cases (which we know are already prime, so there's no need to check). And you don't expect the program to work where n > 4 (and n=5 is the first non-prime).

Comment: The program should theoretically function for n > 4, although that will never work in practice, as we only know of 5 Fermat primes.

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose of theoretically working for all Fermat primes, since there are only 5 known terms.

Comment: You don't appear to have responded to jstnthms's comment, and thus I still don't understand the challenge. Are we just supposed to output `2^(2^n) + 1`, or is there additional work that needs to be done? Why do the answers perform additional tests?

Comment: @CodyGray The testcases are misleading, because this works for `n=1:4`. All fermat primes are of the form `2^2^n+1`, but that does not mean that all numbers of the form `2^2^n+1` are actually prime. This **is** the case for `n=1:4`, but not for `n=5` for example.

Comment: I think that some part of the confusion is that you're saying the input is `n` and the output must be of the form `2^(2^n)+1`. If you use different variables for the input and the exponent then some confusion might be reduced. It might also help if you explicitly state that "n=5 doesn't need to output in reasonable time, but it must not output 4294967297"

Comment: Ok, I edited the question to clarify a little more.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
k=input();F=2
while k:F*=F;k-=3**(F/2)%-~F/F
print-~F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9s2M6@gtERD09rN1oirPCMzJ1Uh28pNy9bNOlvX1lhLS8NN30hTVbfOTd@Nq6AoM68EyPz/3wQA)

Uses [Pépin's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9pin%27s_test).

---

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes**

```python
f=lambda k,F=4:k and f(k-3**(F/2)%-~F/F,F*F)or F**.5+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIVvHzdbEKlshMS9FIU0jW9dYS0vDTd9IU1W3zk3fTcdNy00zv0jBTUtLz1Tb8H8akJ2tkJmnUJSYl56qYappxcVZUJSZVwLSq/kfAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
ÆẸ⁺‘©ÆPµ#ṛ®
```

Uses 1-based indexing.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//w4bhurjigbrigJjCqcOGUMK1I@G5m8Ku//81)

#### How it works

```
ÆẸ⁺‘©ÆPµ#ṛ®  Main link. No argument.

        #    Read an integer n from STDIN and call the chain to the left with
             arguments k = 0, 1, 2, ... until n matches were found.
ÆẸ           Find the integer with prime exponents [k], i.e., 2**k.
  ⁺          Repeat the previous link, yielding 2**2**k.
   ‘         Increment, yielding 2**2**k+1 and...
    ©        copy the result to the register.
     ÆP      Test the result for primality.
          ®  Yield the value from the register, i.e., the n-th Fermar prime.
         ṛ   Yield the result to the right.
```

Comment: Oh, so one uses `ṛ` to clear the result... TIL

Comment: Oh, so one uses `ÆẸ` instead of `2*` for a single integer... TIL

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>45</s>  42 bytes

```perl6
{({1+[**] 2,2,$++}...*).grep(*.is-prime)[$_]}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszZVbqaCWnJ@SqmD7v1qj2lA7WksrVsFIx0hHRVu7Vk9PT0tTL70otUBDSy@zWLegKDM3VTNaJT629n9xYqUCSKOGSrymQlp@kYKBnp6J9X8A)

```perl6
{({1+2**2**$++}...*).grep(*.is-prime)[$_]}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszZVbqaCWnJ@SqmD7v1qj2lDbSEsLiFS0tWv19PS0NPXSi1ILNLT0Mot1C4oyc1M1o1XiY2v/FydWKoB0aajEayqk5RcpGOjpmVj/BwA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  (  # generate a sequence of the Fermat numbers

    {
      1 +
      2 ** 2 **
        $++            # value which increments each time this block is called
    }
    ...                # keep generating until:
    *                  # never stop

  ).grep(*.is-prime)\  # reject all of the non-primes
  [$_]                 # index into that sequence
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 56 bytes

```
(t=n=0;While[t<=#,If[(PrimeQ[s=2^(2^n)+1]),t++];n++];s)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfo8Q2z9bAOjwjMyc1usTGVlnHMy1aI6AoMzc1MLrY1ihOwyguT1PbMFZTp0RbO9Y6D0QUa6r9ByrJK1FwSFNwMPkPAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL (29 Characters)

I'm almost certain this can be improved.

```
{2=+/0=(⍳|⊢)a←1+2*2*⍵:a⋄∇⍵+1}
```

This is a recursive function which checks the number of divisors of 1+2^2^⍵, where ⍵ is the right argument of the function. If the number of divisors is 2, the number is prime, and it returns it, otherwise, it calls the function again with ⍵+1 as a right argument.

### Example

```
{2=+/0=(⍳|⊢)a←1+2*2*⍵:a ⋄ ∇ ⍵+1}¨⍳4
      5 17 257 65537
```

Here I call the function on each of ⍳4 (the numbers 1-4). It applies it to every number in turn.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
e.f&P_ZsIltZQ3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1UvTS0gPqrYM6ckKtD4/39TAA)

Uses 1-indexing.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
Lh^2^2byfP_yTQ
```

[Try online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Lh%5E2%5E2byfP_yTQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4&debug=0)

Main idea "borrowed" from [xnor's answer in another question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97036/61272)

```
Lh^2^2byfP_yTQ

L                    define a function with name y and variable b, which:
 h^2^2b                returns 1+2^2^b
       y             call the recently defined function with argument:
        f    Q         the first number T >= Q (the input) for which:
         P_yT            the same function with argument T returns a prime
                     and implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

#### Code:

Results are 1-indexed.

```
µN<oo>Dp
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0FY/m/x8O5eC//@NAQ)

#### Explanation:

```
µ              # Run the following n succesful times..
 N             #   Push Nn
  oo           #   Compute 2 ** (2 ** n)
    >          #   Increment by one
     D         #   Duplicate
      p        #   Check if the number is prime
               # Implicit, output the duplicated number which is on the top of the stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, <s>12</s> 46 bytes

```
k=>eval('for(i=n=2**2**k+1;n%--i;);1==i&&n')
```

Most of the code is taken up by the prime check, which is from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57617/is-this-number-a-prime/91309#91309).

Comment: Note that it must return the nth *prime* Fermat number, not just the nth Fermat number.

Comment: @poi830 now the prime check takes up most of the function :(

Comment: i think you can say i<2 instead of i==1 becuase zero is also good here? that should reduce be 2 byte

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 61 bytes

```hs
p n=2^2^n;f=(!!)[p x+1|x<-[0..],all((>)2.gcd(p x+1))[2..p x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxCoMwGIT3PsUvOCS0BpvRmkKHDp07ikKoUYPJb4ihWOi7p1a85Y674xvkPCpjorZu8gGenzkoy@741n5CqzCQXoWb72caHaDgDW/w0gmSJLRysBzP36XMqpyx@iSNIeRKOetfLdk2SivO2BrrOlqpUUA7HWCTXJFQZrDT99Z5jSHtgHglW0hh@Nt2LQp4YKAx5j8)

0-based index

**Explanation**

```hs
p n=2^2^n;                                          -- helper function 
                                                    -- that computes what it says
f=                                                  -- main function
  (!!)                                              -- partially evaluate 
                                                    -- index access operator
      [p x+1|                                       -- output x-th fermat number
             x<-[0..],                              -- try all fermat number indices
                      all                 [2..p x]  -- consider all numbers smaller F_x
                                                    -- if for all of them...
                         ((>)2                      -- 2 is larger than...
                              .gcd(p x+1))          -- the gcd of F_x 
                                                    -- and the lambda input 
                                                    -- then it is a Fermat prime!   
                                                  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
!fṗmȯ→‼`^2N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/XzHt4c7puSfWP2qb9KhhT0Kckd////9NAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 26 bytes

```
~3\{{(.*).,(;{*}*)1$%}do}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v844prpaQ09LU09Hw7paq1ZL01BFtTYlv1br/38TAA)

0-indexed

```
~                            # Parse n to a number
 3                           # Push 3
  \{                    }*   # Execute this block n times, this block gets the next Fermat prime
    {                }do     # While the number is composite
     (.*)                    # Go to the next Fermat number
         .,(;                # Make an array from 1 to (F_n)-1
             {*}*            # Multiply the numbers to get ( (F_n)-1 )!
                 )           # Increment it
                  1$%        # This will be 0 iff the Fermat number is prime
```

The primality test used here is [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem#Primality_tests).